# Annihilators of a module.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, and $M$ a (left say) $R$ module. For subgroups $M_i$ in $M$, I have been able to prove

$$\left(\sum_{i\in I}M_{i}\right)^{0}=\bigcap_{i\in I}M_{i}^{0}$$
$$\sum_{i\in I}M_{i}^{0}\subset\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}M_{i}\right)^{0}$$

Where $N^0=\left\{n\in N\vert rn=0 \textrm{ for all }r\in R\right\}$ for a subset $N$ of $M$.

Have I got these right, and is it true that the bottom one is just an inclusion, as opposed to an equality, in general? Does this change if the $M_i$ are submodules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top one is correct and the bottom one is just an inclusion.

Take two faithful modules $A$ and $B$ (faithful means they have zero annihilator.). Then form $M=A\times B$ and consider $A$ and $B$ as submodules of $M$.

On one hand, $A\cap B=\{0\}$, so it's annihilator is $R$.

On the other hand, the sum of their annihilators is $\{0\}+\{0\}=\{0\}$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks